# RegAsm.exe のバージョンについて

Tags: windows, .net

以下の各フォルダにRegAsm.exeがありますが、バージョンによってレジストリへの登録結果も異なるのでしょうか。それとも、どのRegAsm.exeを使用しても同じ結果になるのでしょうか？

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まず

- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework は32bit
- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64 は64bit

という違いがあります。COMは32bitと64bitとで別管理されているため、登録したい側もしくは両方で実行する必要があります。
次に

- v2.0.50727 は2系列（2.0～3.5.1）
- v4.0.30319 は4系列（4.0～）

の違いがあります。基本的にはどちらでも動作します。とはいえ登録したいアセンブリを2系列 / 4系列のどちらで動作させたいかに従って選択されるとよいでしょう。
例えば、2系列で動作させたい場合、その環境に4系列がインストールされていない可能性があるためv4.0.30319は使わない方が無難です。